# Signing for "Runner" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I can't Run my App on my iPhone in Release mode but I can Run it on Debug mode.
In Release mode I get this error even though I am a-signed to a Team.

`Signing for "Runner" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.`

I tried to sign-out from the Team and sign-in again and I also restarted Xcode.

Thank you for any Help LG

Is this right?
[image]

Comment: Be sure that you are selecting the team for All, not only debug mode as demonstrated here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp3jq.jpg

Comment: @Akif i added a picture, is this right?

Comment: No. It is not right.

Comment: You need to set the team for all build modes.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I assume that you did not select the team for all. It is only set for debug mode.

[image]

Comment: This Xcode never ceases to amaze me with its way to fix things :3

Answer (score 7):

For those who doesn't want to add a development team id, you can do the following:

1- Open Podfile

2- Add the following

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

3- Pod install

4- Run your project

Comment: This worked for me. I have development teams selected in Xcode but I still couldn't `flutter run` onto my device. I have spent many many hours on this and paid for Apple Developer accounts to try and fix it (seemed to via Xcode running but not flutter run). I'm not very familiar with Podfiles, I assume it's saying "Don't sign if running on a physical device"? Does this have any consequences down the line with releasing?

Comment: If you are running your app on a physical device you need a signing certificate, you need to add a developer account, but this solution is to prevent other libraries from requesting your apple signing certificate @DecafCoder

Comment: Ok thank you. I was led to believe that you could run more recent Flutter applications on your devices without a paid Apple developer account. I'll look into "other libraries requesting the apple signing certificate" so I understand this a bit more.

Answer (score 4):

Whole steps from App store to XCode with Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles:
Step1: To Certificates, IDs & Profiles item
[image]
Step2: Adding new Certificates
[image]
[image]
Step3: Adding your personal certification key from the macOS Keychain Access
[image]
Step4: Adding your Identifiers
[image]
Step5: The Bundle ID should have the same name between App store and Xcode
[image]
[image]
Step6: Adding your Profiles
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: can I generate a .ipa file, I just need a .ipa file, I have a free developer account

Comment: @AhsanAbrar sorry I didn't try it before but I will try it.

Answer (score 4):

I had this after updating to XCode 14. Error is in my Flutter project.

I've added these lines to my post-install script in `Podfile` to disable code signing.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

For me I had to change my iOS Deployment Target from 8 to 9 or above, after selecting the development team.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Build Settings Tab]For me I had to go to the Build Settings tab, search for Development Team and select a value from one of the available options.  Changing the value on the Signing and Capabilities tab was not cascading through to the Build Settings tab.  This is likely another XCode bug in xCode 12.